# How to negate every number on a list except a specific number? Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm relatively new to haskell, and know that we can use the negation to negate a list. The negation does not negate the number zero in a regular list of type float, int, and integer. But what if you had a list of a different data type? If I negate a different data type, then the number zero in that list will also be negated. Is there a way to not negate numbers like 0 and 0.0 in the list?

Comment: Those results you’re getting are _very_ strange. Firstly, `negate` should give you a type error when you apply it to a list. And there’s no such thing as `-0`! So this certainly can’t be the `negate` from `Prelude`… where does your `negate` function come from?

Comment: @bradrn it is from prelude. Sorry I added the map in before negate on the question. But ```Test``` is a data that takes a list of double

Comment: Thanks! But I still can’t replicate your results: I get `map negate [1,2,0,5,3,-9,0,2] == [-1,-2,0,-5,-3,9,0,-2]`, without the `-0`s. How are you printing the results — with GHCi, or otherwise?

Comment: @bradrn I have tried doing this directly from ghci and reading from a file. either way, I keep get -0.0

Comment: Strange… could you edit in a copy of your GHCi session?

Comment: Actually, now I’m thinking it could be due to the definition of `Test`. How is `Test` defined? Does it have its own `Show` instance?

Comment: @bradrn yes ```Test``` is deriving Show and Eq

Comment: What is the definition of `Test`?

Comment: @bradrn ```data Test = Test [Double] deriving (Show, Eq)```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say

> The negation does not negate the number zero in a regular list of type float

but this assertion is incorrect. See:

```
> negate 0 :: Float
-0.0
> negate 0 :: Double
-0.0
> map negate [0] :: [Float]
[-0.0]
```

The behavior of the rest of your code follows directly from this fact. For further reading I highly recommend [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/%7Edwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf), which includes an in-depth discussion of why floating point must have a negative zero distinct from zero. But the short version is this sentence from page 201:

> If zero did not have a sign, then the relation (1/(1/x)) = x would fail to hold when x = ±∞.