# How do you not negate a number on a list?

Tags: haskell

I know that in Haskell, we can negate a number by doing `negate`. But what if I wanted to negate everything on a list except a certain number?

Lets say I have a function called `helpnegate` which takes in a list. Assuming the list is `[1,0,2,4,8]`, how do you negate every number on that list except the number 4? So if I did `helpnegate ([1,0,2,4,8])` I should get `[-1,0,-2,4,-8]`.

This is my attempt:

```
helpnegate a
        | a == 4 = (0:helpnegate tail)
        | otherwise = (negate a: helpnegate tail)
```

Here I tried to do if `a` was a 4 then I call the function and move to the next, if it was not a 4 I negated that number and called the helped method to the next number. This didn't work.

Comment: Can you write a function that negates a single number unless it's 4?

Comment: @DanielWagner I entered my concept above

Comment: What exactly does "it didn’t work" mean? Does it by any chance mean that you got the value 0 where you expected 4?

Comment: Just return `a` itself (or `4`).

Comment: I think however `helpnegate tail` is the problem here, and the fact that `helpnegate` should work on a list, not a single element.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Sorry Im new to haskell so maybe I'm missing some tricks. what I mean when I said a == 4 is to re run the method but move on to the next number, I thought that traversing a list is to do 0: name of function tail

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to negate every number on a list except a specific number? Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64299757/how-to-negate-every-number-on-a-list-except-a-specific-number-haskell)

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica I don't think that's a good dupe target, because the question is really confusion about floating-point negative zero, and the given answer wouldn't help at all here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a mapping, so you can work with [`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map):

```
helpnegate :: (Num a, Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
helpnegate = map f
    where f 4 = 4
          f x = -x
```

so `f` is the function that maps each individual element. In case it is `4`, we return `4`. In case it is something else (`x`), we return `-x`. For example:

```
Prelude> helpnegate [1,0,2,4,8]
[-1,0,-2,4,-8]
```

Comment: oh I see, I didn't know you could just do -x for any none number 4. Thank you for this!

Comment: @Danzz: well it uses pattern matching. So it will first match with `4`. If that fails, it will fallback on the `f x = -x` clause.